# Factoring a number placing into array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Method `testPerfect` is supposed to receive a number from `getPerfect`, factor the number and put the numbers in an array.
I currently have the array printing, but all zeros. Any suggestions as to put the factors of a number into an array?

```
public class aermel_Perfect
{
public static void main ( String args [] )
{
    int gN;
    int gP = getPerfect();
    int [] array = new int[100];
    //int printFactors;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}


public static int getNum() //Get amount of numbers to check
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
System.out.print( "How many numbers would you like to test? " );
int count = input.nextInt();
int perfect = 1;
boolean vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
while(!vN)
{
    System.out.print (" How many numbers would you like to test? ");
    count = input.nextInt();
    vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
}
return count;
}   

public static boolean validateNum( int count, int perfect  ) //Check if number is valid
{
if (( count <= 0) || ( perfect <= 0))

{ 
    System.out.print( "Non-positive numbers are not allowed.\n");
}



else 
{
    return true;
}
return false;


}
public static int getPerfect() //Gets the numbers to test
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
int perfect = -1;
int count = getNum();
System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: " );
perfect = input.nextInt();  
boolean vN = validateNum(perfect, count);
while (!vN) 
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: ");
    perfect = input.nextInt();
    vN=validateNum(perfect, count);
}
return perfect;
}


public static int[] testPerfect( int perfect, int[] array )

{
testPerfect(perfect, array);
int limit = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(perfect));
int index = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <=limit; i++)
{
    array[index++] = i;
    perfect /= i;
}
array[index] = perfect;

return array;


}






}
```

Comment: That is some mess. Your `testPerfect()` is never being called. And you are getting an array of `0..0` because inside your main you have just created a new array and got it printed.

Comment: As i gone through your code, you are just declaring the array, and printing the array itself. You are not storing the perfect number that is read, into the array. Store your perfect numbers and then print the array. And where did you called the testPerfect();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that maybe?
First you need to call the `testPerfect()` from your main with the `gP` received from `getPerfect()` and the `array` as parameter. 
Second you need to remove the call `testPerfect()` which is the first line of the method `testPerfect()` else this would result in an infinite recursive calls.

```
public class aermel_Perfect
{
public static void main ( String args [] )
{
    int gN;
    int gP = getPerfect();
    int [] array = new int[100];
    array=testPerfect(gP,array);
    //int printFactors;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}


public static int getNum() //Get amount of numbers to check
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
System.out.print( "How many numbers would you like to test? " );
int count = input.nextInt();
int perfect = 1;
boolean vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
while(!vN)
{
    System.out.print (" How many numbers would you like to test? ");
    count = input.nextInt();
    vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
}
return count;
}   

public static boolean validateNum( int count, int perfect  ) //Check if number is valid
{
if (( count <= 0) || ( perfect <= 0))

{ 
    System.out.print( "Non-positive numbers are not allowed.\n");
}



else 
{
    return true;
}
return false;


}
public static int getPerfect() //Gets the numbers to test
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
int perfect = -1;
int count = getNum();
System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: " );
perfect = input.nextInt();  
boolean vN = validateNum(perfect, count);
while (!vN) 
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: ");
    perfect = input.nextInt();
    vN=validateNum(perfect, count);
}
return perfect;
}


public static int[] testPerfect( int perfect, int[] array )

{
//testPerfect(perfect, array);
int limit = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(perfect));
int index = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <=limit; i++)
{
    array[index++] = i;
    perfect /= i;
}
array[index] = perfect;

return array;


}






}
```